# MySQL inner join two columns on one column

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I'm stuck on the inner join scenario for my tables. Can you please help me? What I am doing wrong here?

Here is the scenario that I'm trying to do:

I have billing and shipping country/states columns which I am trying to populate with inner join, but somehow it is not working. Thanks a lot for your help:

```php
 $sql = $this->connection->query("SELECT * FROM ".TBL_USERS." 
    INNER JOIN ".TBL_USER_LEVEL." ON ".TBL_USERS.".userlevel = ".TBL_USER_LEVEL.".user_level_id 
    INNER JOIN ".TBL_COUNTRIES." ON ".TBL_USERS.".country OR ".TBL_USERS.".bcountry = ".TBL_COUNTRIES.".country_id
    INNER JOIN ".TBL_STATES." ON ".TBL_USERS.".states OR ".TBL_USERS.".bstates  = ".TBL_STATES.".states_id
    WHERE ".TBL_USERS.".username = '$username'");
```

i changed the query to; and the error im gettin is

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'countries'' in

```
 $sql = $this->connection->query("SELECT * FROM ".TBL_USERS." 
    INNER JOIN ".TBL_USER_LEVEL." ON ".TBL_USERS.".userlevel = ".TBL_USER_LEVEL.".user_level_id 
    INNER JOIN ".TBL_COUNTRIES." ON ".TBL_USERS.".country = ".TBL_COUNTRIES.".country_id
    INNER JOIN ".TBL_COUNTRIES." ON ".TBL_USERS.".bcountry = ".TBL_COUNTRIES.".country_id
    INNER JOIN ".TBL_STATES." ON ".TBL_USERS.".states = ".TBL_STATES.".states_id

    INNER JOIN ".TBL_STATES." ON ".TBL_USERS.".bstates = ".TBL_STATES.".states_id

    WHERE ".TBL_USERS.".username = '$username'");
```

OK here is correct syntax thanks a lot to @Tiberiu-Ionuț Stan

```
$sql = $this->connection->query("SELECT * FROM ".TBL_USERS." 
    LEFT JOIN ".TBL_COUNTRIES." ON ".TBL_USERS.".country = ".TBL_COUNTRIES.".country_id 

   LEFT JOIN ".TBL_COUNTRIES." AS ".TBL_COUNTRIES."_b ON ".TBL_USERS.".bcountry=".TBL_COUNTRIES."_b.country_id

    INNER JOIN ".TBL_USER_LEVEL." ON ".TBL_USERS.".userlevel = ".TBL_USER_LEVEL.".user_level_id 
    LEFT JOIN ".TBL_STATES." ON ".TBL_USERS.".states = ".TBL_STATES.".states_id 

    LEFT JOIN ".TBL_STATES." AS ".TBL_STATES."_b ON ".TBL_USERS.".bstates=".TBL_STATES."_b.states_id


    WHERE ".TBL_USERS.".username = '$username'");
```

Comment: Are you getting an SQL error? If so, can you post it? At first glance, I don't think you can use OR in the JOIN clauses - doesn't make much sense. Couldn't see in in MySQL documentation anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use OR and AND inside join statements.
I do it all the time.
Here's one that works:

```
  LEFT JOIN `currencies` ON (
   `currency_foreign`=`invoice_entry_amount_currency`
   AND
   `currency_reference`='".$strTransformToCurrency."'
   AND
   `currency_date`=FLOOR(`invoice_paid_timestamp`/86400)*86400
  )
```

Problem is here:

```
   INNER JOIN ".TBL_COUNTRIES." ON ".TBL_USERS.".country = ".TBL_COUNTRIES.".country_id
   INNER JOIN ".TBL_COUNTRIES." ON ".TBL_USERS.".bcountry = ".TBL_COUNTRIES.".country_id
```

MySQL can't decide on which relation to join the countries table (because MySQL thinks .country and .countryb can be different - so after join it doesn't know which columns will be returned or used for conditions and ordering).

Try it like this:

```
  INNER JOIN ".TBL_COUNTRIES." ON ".TBL_USERS.".country = ".TBL_COUNTRIES.".country_id
  INNER JOIN ".TBL_COUNTRIES." AS ".TBL_COUNTRIES."_b ON ".TBL_USERS.".bcountry=".TBL_COUNTRIES."_b.country_id
```

In case you have really big tables, do an EXPLAIN with the full final query including conditions and ordering to find out if MySQL is doing a table copy because of "TBL_USERS AS TBL_USERS_B".

Comment: i'm am getting same error: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'countries''

Comment: Do the same for TBL_STATES ;)

Comment: Add an alias for TBL_STATES just like on the TBL_COUNTRIES as I showed you.

Comment: thanks a  lot for your help i am not getting the error message anymore however i cant not populate any data now all field are empty :) i wanna cry:)

Comment: I made a mistake in that JOIN. add an _b to TBL_COUNTRIES on the expression part too (".TBL_USERS.".bcountry=".TBL_COUNTRIES."_b.country_id). Do the same for TBL_STATES/

Comment: BTW, you might wanna use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN, for it seems you just wanna translate country names.

Comment: thanks a lot you are the man :) my brain just stuck :) now i cant not echo :) both shows the same country and same field name for example
country usa
bcountry usa it suppose to be different i think i need more coffee :)

Comment: Hehe, you need more aliasing. For example: SELECT `countries_b`.`country_name` AS `country_name_b`, ...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use constructs like `JOIN table ON field OR another_field = expression`, unless referenced `field` is of boolean type.

You should use constructs that will return boolean result, in your case something like this:

```sql
$sql = $this->connection->query("SELECT * FROM $TBL_USERS 
    JOIN $TBL_USER_LEVEL ON $TBL_USERS.userlevel = $TBL_USER_LEVEL.user_level_id 
    JOIN $TBL_COUNTRIES ON $TBL_USERS.country = $TBL_COUNTRIES.country_id
      OR $TBL_USERS.bcountry = $TBL_COUNTRIES.country_id
    JOIN $TBL_STATES ON $TBL_USERS.states = $TBL_STATES.states_id
      OR $TBL_USERS.bstates  = $TBL_STATES.states_id
    WHERE $TBL_USERS.username = '$username'");
```

I have also used the variable directly, otherwise lots of string concatenations looks messy.
And your query as is now is open for [SQLi](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: That query is only open for SQL injection if the respective variables are somehow writable directly or indirectly using input params (such as argv, $_GET, etc).

Comment: btw, those aren't variables, they are constants, so it's very unlikely for them to be taking any values from request params.